# Change password on AD domain not working from client machines

Tags: domain, active-directory, password-management

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with AD as primary domain controller. Whenever a user's password expires, he changes it but it is never accepted the next time he tries to login (or from Exchange Server, which we use for e-mail); Hovewer if the password is changed from the PDC itself (or using "Active Directory Users and Computer" program), it is accepted everywhere. All the machines, of course, are part of the domain.

Thank you

Comment: One server and no member servers? I.e. 1 server + everything else clients?

Comment: How many domain controllers have you got ? Have you well configured your replication settings ? I should also recommend to configure your Exchange servers to use the PDC to validate logins.

Comment: It may be that the new password is being cached by the client but not updating the server - I think there is a HotFix for this...

Comment: We only have 1 PDC and everything else is a client. No replication. @BigChris: which hotfix?